# C++ error: braces around scalar initializer for type 'bool'

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I moved to latest GXX compiler and I have the following error:

```
error: braces around scalar initializer for type 'bool'
```

the call is:

```
m_ForReset{std::make_pair(false,false), std::make_pair(false,false)}
```

where `m_ForReset` is:

```
std::pair<bool,bool> m_ForReset[2];
```

Any ideas what may have changed in the (GCC) 4.9.3

my build flags:

```
-pipe -Wno-write-strings -Wno-enum-compare -Wno-write-strings -Wno-psabi -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC  -fpermissive -std=c++11 -O2  -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
```

Comment: Latest gcc is 7.2, not 4.9. You're a few years behind.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: updated to GCC 5.3, but I get the same error... :(

Comment: Post a [MCVE] or no-one will be able to help

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be bug [#60859](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60859), which appeared in 4.9 and was resolved in 5.x.